# If 2 or more functions are parallel,do their primitives always intersect in only one point?

Tags: calculus

So if we had $f(x)=3x+2 $ and $ g(x)=3x+4$,we know these functions are parallel because they have the same slope,but if we integrate we get that they intersect in one point,do all functions that are parallel have the same propriety?

Comment: I meant they intersect in only one point sorry,about the title,sorry for the mistakes!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What dou you mean when you claim that “if we integrate we get that they intersect in one point”.

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)+c$, then $\int f(x)dx=\int (g(x)+c)dx=\int g(x)dx + cx+d$ so their (indefinite) integrals differ by a linear function $cx+d$. If $c\ne 0$, then, indeed, this difference is $0$ at a single point, no matter what $d$ you choose.

Comment: Ok,thank you very much!